# How to get Google's Last Crawl Date for a given URL of mine via the API

Tags: google-api, google-search-console

Given any **URL of a site I "own"**, in **Google Search Console** I can see this information:

[image: screenshot]

I am particularly interested in the **"last crawl date"**.

How do I get the same information with the API (Search Console API or Webmaster Tools API)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. Not via the Google Search Console API, the Webmaster Tools API, or any other Google API for that matter. How Google can design their APIs so poorly is beyond me. Providing access to 100% of the features that you can access through the UI of the same service, is the #1 most basic requirement of an API, and they fail even at that.

There's [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507993/api-for-when-google-crawled-my-site-last-give-a-url) (requesting `https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:<YOUR_URL>...` and scraping the response contents), but you'll start getting "429 too many requests" pretty soon, so it's basically useless unless you only need to make, I don't know, maybe a request every few days.

In practice, there doesn't seem to be any other way than logging the crawler's visits yourself (recognizing it from the user-agent string, validating the IP maybe with a reverse lookup or just against a list).